# Finding the time given distance using vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, algebra-precalculus

Could someone help me with this question please?

Find the time at which the distance of the particle from the origin is 16.
When $$r(t) = (t^2-t+2)\hat{i} + (t^3-3)\hat{j}$$

This is how I found the magnitude

$$\sqrt{\left(t^2-t+2\right)^2+\left(t^3-3\right)^2}=16$$

I expanded the brackets and got rid of the square root

$$t^6+t^4-8t^3+5t^2-4t+13\:=\:256$$

And I've simplified it to here

$$t^3\left(t^2+t-8\right)+\left(5t^2-4t-243\right)=0$$

And now I'm stuck!

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please, show your effort to solve the problem, then I will post a solution.

Comment: Yep i have done that!

Comment: Nice! You could type them in the post using mathjax.

Comment: @begginer: Post it in normal text. I or someone else, will format it for the first time. You can learn and do it yourself next time.

Comment: thanks! i've done that

Comment: Looks like you need to estimate a solution using for example Newton-Raphson $t\approx \:-2.17518\dots ,\:t\approx \:2.60862\dots $